# Dynamically add tables and other components to ZEN PDF Reports

Tags: intersystems-iris

I need a way to programically and dynamically add tables and other controls to a blank Zen Page.

Are there code examples where a global can dynamically create the tables and populate it with data?

Comment: What is "Zen" in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Zen is deprecated in InterSystems IRIS.
If you want to build the UI to IRIS please consider using any popular UI framework e.g. Angular, React or View vs IRIS REST API.
Or take a look at [RAD Studio](https://openexchange.intersystems.com/package/iris-rad-studio) where you can get an automatic UI for your persistent data in IRIS.